# show that if A is not compact, exists a function continuous and bounded without maximum or minimum

Tags: general-topology

show that if A is not compact in $\mathbf{R}$ ,  exists a function continuous and bounded $f:A\to \mathbf{R}$ without maximum or minimum in A.
I showed it by examples but it is not enough for my prof. Could this be demonstrated in a more general way? Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Sorry for being rude. But this is a possible duplicate of [Show that exists a continuous function in $E$ that is not bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327671/show-that-exists-a-continuous-function-in-e-that-is-not-bounded) (notice (ii) in the link post)

Comment: Do you mean that $f$ has neither a maximum nor a minimum?

Comment: It is not a duplicate. The quoted question asked for a bounded function without maximum, here one looks for a bounded function without maximum **and** without minimum. This is somewhat more demanding.